# Apply the same function to a subset of rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the following code to filter the dataframe using type and value column and then deleting any entries with a tdiff >0 and < 3.

```
import pandas as pd  
    
d = {'Timestamp': ['2020-09-02 07:00:00','2020-09-02 07:10:00', '2020-09-02 07:30:00', '2020-09-02 08:00:00', '2020-09-02 10:00:00', '2020-09-02 11:10:00', '2020-09-02 11:30:00'], 
     'type': ['A','A','B','A', 'A','A','B'], 'value': [1,2,3,1,1,2,3]}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
    
unique_type = pd.unique(df['type']).astype(str)  

for i in range(0,len(unique_type)):
    
    df1 = df[df.type == unique_type[i]]
    unique_val = pd.unique(df1['value']).astype(int)  
    
    for j in range(0, len(unique_val)):
        
        df2 = df1[df1.value == unique_val[j]]
        trange = pd.to_datetime(df2.Timestamp)
        tdiff = (trange-min(trange)).dt.total_seconds()/3600
        df2['tdiff'] = tdiff#.round(1)
                   
        df3 = df3.append(df2, ignore_index=True)

df4 = df3[~((df3.tdiff>0) & (df3.tdiff<3))] 

print(df)
df4.sort_values(by=['Timestamp'])
```

While this works, I would like to move away from for loops and use a more efficient code.

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: Is this a general question on how to use functions with dataframes or how to calculate this specific function with a dataframe?

Comment: I have edited the post and provided more details including the expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and `transform` applied with `min`:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'] )
df['tmin'] = df.groupby(['type','value'])['Timestamp'].transform(min)
df['tdiff'] = (df['Timestamp'] - df['tmin']).dt.total_seconds()/3600
df[~((df.tdiff>0) & (df.tdiff<3))]
```

output

```
    Timestamp            type      value  tmin                   tdiff
--  -------------------  ------  -------  -------------------  -------
 0  2020-09-02 07:00:00  A             1  2020-09-02 07:00:00        0
 1  2020-09-02 07:10:00  A             2  2020-09-02 07:10:00        0
 2  2020-09-02 07:30:00  B             3  2020-09-02 07:30:00        0
 4  2020-09-02 10:00:00  A             1  2020-09-02 07:00:00        3
 5  2020-09-02 11:10:00  A             2  2020-09-02 07:10:00        4
 6  2020-09-02 11:30:00  B             3  2020-09-02 07:30:00        4
```

Comment: Hi @piterbarg, thank you for your answer. I have edited the original post as it was too generic and example was missing the expected output.

Comment: @Tanjil see the new answer -- same idea

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code, with `lambda` function

Data:

```
d = {'type': ['A','A','B','C'], 'col1': [1,2,3,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

df:

```
  type  col1
0    A     1
1    A     2
2    B     3
3    C     9
```

```
f = pd.Series(pd.Series(df['type'].unique()).apply(lambda type_: (type_, df[df['type'] == type_].col1.sum()))).to_list()
df['New-column'] = df.type.replace(dict(f))
df.loc[df['New-column'] >= 9, 'New-column'] = np.nan
```

df:

```
  type  col1  New-column
0    A     1         3.0
1    A     2         3.0
2    B     3         3.0
3    C     9         NaN
```